# PHP 7.2 throws an error on WordPress class-wp-hook.php file

Tags: php, wordpress, php-7.2

Site on WP Engine. They're forcing an upgrade to PHP 7.2.

PHP 7.2 - error with /class-wp-hook.php

PHP 7.2
WordPress 5.0
WPEngine

> Warning : Parameter 1 to wp_default_scripts() expected to be a
>   reference, value given in
>   /nas/content/live/*/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 286
>
> Warning : Parameter 1 to wp_default_packages() expected to be a
>   reference, value given in
>   /nas/content/live/*/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 286
>
> Warning : Parameter 1 to wp_default_styles() expected to be a
>   reference, value given in
>   /nas/content/live/*/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 286

Already tried:

- 0 active plugin
- Default WordPress theme.

I will like to solve the problem, not just hide the warning

Comment: It looks like a theme you're using haven't been updated fully, thus passing the wrong expected arguments to the method.